# SQLiteException: near "u": syntax error (code 1)

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm getting an error on my rawQuery which I am trying to join two tables?

```
 SELECT Calories FROM CalorieIntake_Table c  INNER JOIN Users_Table u ON c.USER_ID = u.U_IDWHERE u.U_ID =?
```

Here is the code for the Query:

```
 public CalorieIntake getuserIntake(int id) {
    CalorieIntake calorieIntake = null;
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    final String UserintQuery = "SELECT " + KEY_CALORIES + " FROM "
            + TABLE_CALORIE_INTAKE + " c " + " INNER JOIN " + TABLE_USERS + " u " +
            "ON" + " c." + KEY_USER_ID + " = u." + KEY_U_ID + "WHERE u." + KEY_U_ID + " =?";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(UserintQuery, new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});

    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        calorieIntake = new CalorieIntake(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getDouble(2));


    }

    return calorieIntake;
}
```

Comment: Change `"WHERE u."` to `" WHERE u."`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK dayumh! hawk eye! :D

Comment: Nvm. Beat to it by hawkeye D:

Comment: Any time you build SQL by strings it's a good rule of thumb to check the beginning of all immediate strings to make sure they're sane. Good formatting helps a lot with this. Better yet, don't build queries like this :(

Comment: That should be an answer so this doesn't show as unanswered.